# The correct way to test a main effect by comparing mixed-effects models using anova() in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I want to compare two mixed-effects models using `anova()` for the main effect of a fixed factor. I understand the test will compare the baseline model including the predictor against a nested model excluding the predictor. But when there is an interaction involving the fixed factor I want to test, should I exclude the interaction from the baseline model before comparing two models?

For example, here is the baseline model:

```
mod1 <- lmer(y ~ a + b + a:b + (1|c), data, REML = FALSE)
```

I want to test the main effect of `b`, so I created the nested model:

```
mod2 <- lmer(y ~ a + (1|c), data, REML = FALSE)
```

To test the main effect, should I compare `mod2` against `mod1`, or against the following `mod3`?

```
mod3 <- lmer(y ~ a + b + (1|c), data, REML = FALSE)
```

Comment: I would do it with the full model otherwise you do not know whether the effect of b would still be present when the random structure is included. Thus I would compare models 1 and 2.

Comment: The difference between `mod1` and `mod2` is two parameters, the regression coefficient for `b` and then for `a:b`. If you simply want to know whether adding the main effect of `b` improves the fit over just having the main effect of `a`, then you should test `mod2b<- lmer(y ~ a + b + (1|c), data, REML = FALSE)` and run an `anova` comparing mod2 and mod2b. It is not clear to me whether you simply want to test whether the interaction is necessary or the interaction+main effect.

Comment: @CatM, It's my typo. I should have included the random structure in mod3.

Comment: @ErikRuzek I don't want to test whether the interaction is necessary. Do you suggest if I just want to test the effect of ```b```, I will have to drop the interaction from the full model?

Comment: That would be the cleanest test, yes.